# Ninject Activation Error: No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

Hi I am attempting to complete a lift and shift of an aged WCF service and I have come across an error.

Basically I get the following message:

> Error activating Searcher{Product} No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path:
>     3) Injection of dependency Searcher{Product} into parameter productSearcher of constructor of type ProductSearchService
>     2) Injection of dependency ProductSearchService into parameter instance of constructor of type NinjectIISHostingServiceHost{ProductSearchService}
>     1) Request for NinjectIISHostingServiceHost{ProductSearchService}

Suggestions:

1. Ensure that you have defined a binding for Searcher{Product}.
2. If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
3. Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
4. If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
5. If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

Here is the Ninject Binding Module:

```
public override void Load()
{
   Bind<Searcher<Product>>().To<ProductWebHelpSearcher>().WhenInjectedInto<ProductSearchService>().InSingletonScope();
   Bind<Searcher<Product>>().To<ProductSearcher>().InRequestScope();
}
```

and a copy of the NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Load<NinjectBindingsMappingModule>();
    }
}
```

and finally a copy of the WCF Service:

```
public class ProductSearchService : IProductSearchService
{
    private readonly Searcher<Product> _productSearcher;

    public ProductSearchService(Searcher<Product> productSearcher)
    {
        _productSearcher = productSearcher;
    }
}
```

There are several projects that have a similar setup and I am not getting the same issue as I am here, the only difference is that those apps are MVC and not WCF.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the second binding to Searcher<Product>?

Comment: @AndreasAppelros Same error, the thing is that the exact same type of Searcher<Product> is set up in the same way in another project, apart from the WhenInjectedInto type and the fact that, that application is an MVC web app not WCF.

Comment: Make sure you don't create binding for `NamespaceOne.Product` and injecting `NamespaceTwo.Product`

Comment: It could be that your bindings are not executed in your MVC app, have you tried setting a breakpoint in your module?

Answer (score 0):

After checking the namespaces as suggested by Alexander, it seems that the svc .cs was using one names space, and the Ninject mapping module was given another. I have now made them the same and it's all in working order.